# C++11 overload of `M operator+(M&&,M&&)`

Tags: operator-overloading, move-semantics, c++11

**Update:** clarification, more clear focus and shortened example:

- **Can I circumvent the `M op+(M&&,M&&)` overload?** Assuming, I want good handling of *RValues*? I guess the other three overloads *are* required.

Reason why I have the `(&&,&&)` overload in the first place:

- Normally I would not provide `M op+(&&,&&)`, but I seem to need it: When providing overloads for `(&&,&)` and `(&,&&)` the compiler gets into an ambiguity. Is there a better way to resolve it then to add another implementation variant?

You can also look at the [complete](http://ideone.com/KqPjw) code.

```
struct Matrix {
...
  // 2ary ops
  friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix &a, Matrix &&b     ) { b+=a; return move(b); }
  friend Matrix operator+(Matrix &&a,      const Matrix &b) { a+=b; return move(a); }
  friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix &a, Matrix v)        { v+=a; return v; }
  friend Matrix operator+(Matrix &&a,      Matrix &&b)      { a+=b; return move(a); }
  // ... same for operator*
  // ... assume impl of operator+=,*= and move semantics
};

int main() {
  Matrix a{2},b{3},c{4},d{5};
  Matrix x = a*b + c*d;  // reuires &&,&& overload
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: -1: First, what's your question? You seem to be just saying, "Here's some code. What do you think?" Second, stop using &&. This is about the 6th question in several days where you've asked about these things. They are something that you should **rarely** use, and should only be used by people who are either writing a move constructor/assignment, writing a forwarding function, or who _really_ know how they work.

Comment: Oh, and BTW: accepted answers are not what you award to particularly good answers. They're what you give to the _right_ answer. You've had a lot of perfectly acceptable answers in the past few days, but you've accepted very few of them. Indeed, you've posted a "Thanks" reply to some of them, but still didn't bother to accept them.

Comment: @Nicol: I do accept answers. I usually wait a couple of days if not all my points covered to get everyone the chance, who might only look at stackoverflow once a week. Also, sometimes a discussion for some time is also helpful. Because there is a section where I can easily see what I did not accept yet, I do that regularly and see whats still open -- consolidating it. Be assured, I accept answers that are *right*, that helped me most. But there are also some, where I have nothing to accept. I take you input and check right now for open questions.

Comment: Ok, the first version of the question was too broad. I narrowed it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following helper function returns the first value if it an rvalue, otherwise the second value (which may be an rvalue, but may not be).

```
template <class T1, class T2>
typename std::enable_if<! std::is_reference<T1>::value, T1&&>::type 
  get_rvalue(T1&& t1, T2&& t2) { return std::forward<T1>(t1); }

template <class T1, class T2>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_reference<T1>::value, T2&&>::type 
  get_rvalue(T1&& t1, T2&& t2) { return std::forward<T2>(t2); }
```

The following helper function returns the other value not returned above.

```
template <class T1, class T2>
typename std::enable_if<! std::is_reference<T1>::value, T1&&>::type 
  get_non_rvalue(T1&& t1, T2&& t2) { return std::forward<T2>(t2); }

template <class T1, class T2>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_reference<T1>::value, T2&&>::type 
  get_non_rvalue(T1&& t1, T2&& t2) { return std::forward<T1>(t1); }
```

This just compares if two types are the same, ignoring references and const.

```
template <class T1, class T2>
struct is_same_decay : public std::is_same<
  typename std::decay<T1>::type, 
  typename std::decay<T2>::type
> {};
```

Then we can do just one overload for each function (using templates) like the following:

```
// 2ary ops
template <class M1, class M2>
friend typename std::enable_if< 
  is_same_decay<M1, Matrix>::value &&
  is_same_decay<M2, Matrix>::value,
Matrix>::type
operator+(M1&& a, M2&& b) 
{ 
  Matrix x = get_rvalue(std::forward<M1>(a), std::forward<M2>(b)); 
  x += get_non_rvalue(std::forward<M1>(a), std::forward<M2>(b)); 
  return x; 
}

template <class M1, class M2>
friend typename std::enable_if< 
  is_same_decay<M1, Matrix>::value &&
  is_same_decay<M2, Matrix>::value,
Matrix>::type
operator*(M1&& a, M2&& b) 
{ 
  Matrix x = get_rvalue(std::forward<M1>(a), std::forward<M1>(b)); 
  x *= get_non_rvalue(std::forward<M1>(a), std::forward<M1>(b)); 
  return x; 
}
```

Note above, if either `M1` or `M2` is an rvalue, `get_rvalue(a, b)` will return an rvalue, hence in this case `Matrix x` will be populated by a move, not a copy. Named return value optimisation will probably ensure that there is no copy (or even move) required into the return value, as `x` will be constructed in the place of the return value.

Full code is [here](http://ideone.com/8uPIb).

Comment: I think I understand 80% of that. Does it also work if both args are *RValues*? Isn't there a case when `get_rvalue(a,b)` and `get_non_rvalue(a,b)` will return the same result (`b`, I think?) Also, should not the `get_...()` functions return `forward<Tx>( tx )` to make be sure for all ref-kinds, to make it "perfect"? Third, just an observation: this definitely only works for operators that a commutative, right? But with your explanation I should be able to save some overloads for `operator/()`, too.

Comment: Fourth, I can not see how the compiler can get rid of the `Matrix x = ...` copy by *named return value optimization* (because I am not an expert with that. So, it does not mean he can not, of course). Is that just a "feeling" if yours, or are you sure? When I provide the "traditional" 4 overloads, I can see, that there will be no unnecessary (full) object construction. I do count only one (full) construction for an expressions like `Matrix x = a+b+c*d+d*e*f+g*h`. Are you sure that is also the case for your solution, with the `Matrix x = ...`?

Comment: Hi towi. I've edited my answer and did a number of fixes. Now there should be a minimum of full object constructions, in the case of `Matrix x = a*b+c*d`, `a*b` must construct an object (as neither are temporaries) and `c*d` must construct (as again, neither are temporaries) but then the `+` in `(a*b)+(c*d)` can be done just using a move, as at least one of `(a*b)` and `(c*d)` are temporaries (in this case, both are).

Comment: You are right of course, the subexpressions create a temp. My original example was `a+b*c+d`, and I was to hasty expanding that. But I am glad I could contribute. I assume I may present your excellent code when I explain these things...

Answer (score 1):

```
Matrix& operator=(Matrix&& o) { swap(*this,o); };
```

First, your Matrix class has nothing (as of yet) that needs moving, so you shouldn't bother writing one. Like a copy constructor, *only define one if you need to*. Let the compiler take care of it unless you have a legitimate need (like storing a naked pointer).

Second, that function of yours doesn't move; it *swaps*. An "idiomatic" swap-based move involves a temporary, like this:

```
Matrix temp;
swap(o, temp);
swap(temp, *this);
```

---

```
friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix &a, Matrix &&b     ) { b+=a; return move(b); }
friend Matrix operator+(Matrix &&a,      const Matrix &b) { a+=b; return move(a); }
friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix &a, Matrix v)        { v+=a; return v; }
friend Matrix operator+(Matrix &&a,      Matrix &&b)      { a+=b; return move(a); }
```

What are you trying to accomplish here? Again, your object doesn't have anything that gets moved; there's no point in doing this. Just because you *could* move something, doesn't mean you should. If you really wanted to cut down on code duplication, you would do things normally:

```
friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix &a, const Matrix &b) { Matrix temp = a + b; return temp; }
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, in my first version of the question I had nothing to move. I overhauled the example code, assuming there *is* something to move. And in `operator=` there was an error, not returning `this`.